# What is wrong with this code using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to coding and now I'm trying to write a code that gets the text data form a file and replace the present text with the new one. I'm using AJAX to do the task but the problem is first I'm getting the error message and then expected answer The error message is what I have included in the code to display when there is error. Even though i'm getting the desired answer I want to know why the error message is displayed. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function loadXML() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
            }    
            else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MICROSOFT.XMLHTTP")
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
                else {
                    alert(" there is a error in your code");  
                }   
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","robots.txt", true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
    </script>
</head>    
<body>
    <p id="p1">This is Text</p>
    <button id="b1" onclick="loadXML()">Click me </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all, Why are you loading 2 jquery files? remove one of them. they are the same. one is minified and the other one is not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your if-block in onreadystatechange. During the request and response, xmlhttp.readyState changes multiple times and onreadystatechange is called every time this happens.

If you do it like this, it may work:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
         if( xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
             document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         } else {
             alert(" there is a error in your code");  
         }
    }
```

It is simpler, however, to use the other event-methods like onload and onerror, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIXMLHttpRequestEventTarget).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is no response form my web browser when I click "CLICK ME" button after I change the code as you prescribed

Comment: Did you copy the code directly or edit your own? There was a mistake in my code (http.onreadystatechange instead of xmlhttp.onreadystatechange).

Answer (score 0):

1- include 1 jQuery file `jquery-1.9.0.js` same as `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` but `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` is minified file

2- what is the Error message from javaconsole log ?

3- you are using jQuery so why you are working with `XMLHttpRequest` when jQuery `$.get` already using best of HttpRequest for all browsers

you can replace your JS code with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $.get('robots.txt',function(data){ $('#p1').html(data) });

});
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you please tell me how to call the function in " onclick" area.

Comment: sure `$('#b1').click(function(){ //ur code here  });`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a webserver ? Ajax doesn't work from local file url : 'file://...'

Answer (score 0):

`alert(" there is a error in your code");`
Actually there is no error in your code. `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` is called in different states of the request. Thats why you check for `xmlhttp.readyState == 4`. Learn more about the different stages here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp
So your code is running fine, you just alert an error message, that is not an error at all.